# Oozie coordinator scheduling using cron expression giving error

Tags: hadoop, cron, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I have scheduled a coordinator using cron expression 
frequency = "20 3 * * 2-4" but it gives error.
The oozie coordinator logs say "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" : paramter [frequency]=[20 3 * * 2-4] must be an integer . Parsing error for input String : "20 3 * * 2-4"

HDP version : 2.5.3
Oozie Client build version : 4.2.0.2.5.3.0-37

..
..

Comment: Which version of Oozie? Did you build it yourself, or was it bundled with a distro? What about sharing the whole Coordinator script (after some obfuscation)? And finally, do you have a *question*?

Comment: <coordinator-app name = "CO_PolicyTexttoORC" frequency="20 7 * * 2-6" start="${startTime1}" end="${endTime1}" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2" >

<datasets> ..</datasets>
<action>..</action>

</coordinator-app>

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting Oozie to apply XML schema for Coordinator... in version **0.2** of that schema.

The documentation hints that [CRON syntax worked with schema 0.2](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.3._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency) but I'm pretty sure that CRON scheduling was introduced in Oozie V4.0 (and documented in V4.1) -- and since Oozie V4.0 [introduced](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#Oozie_Coordinator_Schema_0.4) schema **0.4** I believe that the documentation is wrong.

Bottom line: requesting `xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4"` should allow Oozie to parse your CRON schedule correctly.

Comment: Not working even after using xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4". Same parsing error.

Comment: It works. In datasets this cron frequency wont work. I have schedule only in corrdinator, its working thanks.